# undefined index when using multidimensional array

Tags: php, jquery, html

I keep getting an undefined index for `vidid` in my `$_POST when using multi dimensional array and I don't know why I am getting this?

Below is jquery:

```
var videocounter = 0;

function stopVideoUpload(success, videoID, videofilename){

      var result = '';
      videocounter++;

      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span class="videomsg'+videocounter+'">The file was uploaded successfully</span>';
            $('.hiddenvid').append('<input type="hidden" name="vidid[" + videocounter + "][]" id="'+videoID+'" value="' + videoID + '" />');



      return true;   
}
```

Below is the $_POST:

```
$vidresults = $_POST['vidid'];
```

Comment: You aren't doing string concatenation correctly in your javascript. (quote problems near videocounter)

Comment: How come it doesn't display in error console that I used incorrect quotes? Normally when I used wrong quotes it gives me an error

Comment: It will not show a console error because it's not incorrect quotes. You just did the concatenation wrong. If you use a debugger you will see that you were outputting a string instead of concatenating the variable

Comment: The syntax was correct, however the result wasn't what you wanted it to be. That is why it went through without error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Watch out for the quotes, f.ex this:

```
'<input type="hidden" name="vidid[" + videocounter + "]
```

Should probably be

```
'<input type="hidden" name="vidid[' + videocounter + ']
```

You can easily spot this in the syntax highlighting here at SO,

Answer (score 0):

Bad quotes. Change:

```
$('.hiddenvid').append('<input type="hidden" name="vidid[" + videocounter + "][]" id="'+videoID+'" value="' + videoID + '" />');
```

To:

```
$('.hiddenvid').append('<input type="hidden" name="vidid[' + videocounter + '][]" id="'+videoID+'" value="' + videoID + '" />');
```